# How to conditionally hide elements of an Angular Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an Angular Directive.

Here is the replica of it's template

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div> <!-- to be hidden in some places -->
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This directive isn't dynamic. It just renders once when the page is loaded. I want to use the same directive in some places but without a particular div. What's the best way to go about it?

#### I've thought about and researched the following

I am relatively new and I might be wrong with my approach. Please point the mistakes that I may have made.

```
<div ng-show="somemodel"></div>
```

- Use some model to show or hide it. But the problem is that I will have to create a model/variable in every respective controller.
- Change the link function depending on the value passed to the directive and hide the div
- I don't see the use of a watch as nothing's going to change once the user loads a page.

Is there any way to pass in a value/config while using the directive? This way everything related to that directive can be clubbed together.

```
<div directive-name showParticularDiv = "true" />
<div directive-name showParticularDiv = "false" />
```

**Edit after implementation of some ways.**

View

```
<div date-picker-directive></div>
```

Template

```
<div class="timebuttons">
    <div class="ui button" ng-click="vm.getPredefinedDataButtons(365)">LAST YEAR</div> 
    <div class="ui button" ng-click="vm.getPredefinedDataButtons(90)">LAST QUARTER</div>
    <div class="ui button" ng-click="vm.getPredefinedDataButtons(31)">LAST MONTH</div> 
    <div class="ui button" ng-click="vm.getPredefinedDataButtons(7)">LAST WEEK</div>
    <div class="ui button" ng-click="vm.getPredefinedDataButtons(0)" ng-show="vm.showToday">TODAY</div>
    <div class="ui button blackbody" id="givedate" ng-click="showRange = !showRange">CUSTOM RANGE</div>
</div>
```

This works. If I use a variable from the controller to hide/show the div, it works fine.

If I use the directive's scope instead of a model from the controller, ng-click stops working.

```
<div date-picker-directive show-today="false" />
```

ng-click in the template stops working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to pass through attributes(as in your last code block) and bind in `scope` directive's property. More about scope binding you can read [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-). Also, important to remember that directive name and it's attributes will be converted to kebab-case, so if you have attribute or directive with name `myItem` it should be written as `my-item` in HTML.

```js
angular
.module('app', [])
.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.show = false;
}).directive('dynamicDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      showHidden: '=?'
    },
    template: '<div ng-show="showHidden">hidden</div>'
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="show">Show hidden
  <div dynamic-directive show-hidden="show"></div>
</div>
```

In your case directive cannot call controller's function until you pass it through attributes or share scope with directive(example based on the first option):

```js
angular
.module('app', [])
.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.show = false;
  $scope.getPredefinedDataButtons = function(amount) {
    console.log('Called with amount', amount);
  };
}).directive('dynamicDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      showHidden: '=?',
      callback: '&?'
    },
    templateUrl: '/templates/dynamic-dir.html',
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="show">Show hidden
  <div dynamic-directive show-hidden="show" callback="getPredefinedDataButtons(amount)"></div>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="/templates/dynamic-dir.html">
    <div class="timebuttons">
    <div class="ui button" ng-click="callback({amount: 365})">LAST YEAR</div> 
    <div class="ui button" ng-click="callback({amount: 90})">LAST QUARTER</div>
    <div class="ui button" ng-click="callback({amount: 31})">LAST MONTH</div> 
    <div class="ui button" ng-click="callback({amount: 7})">LAST WEEK</div>
    <div class="ui button" ng-click="callback({amount: 0})" ng-show="showHidden">TODAY</div>
    <div class="ui button blackbody" id="givedate" ng-click="showRange = !showRange">CUSTOM RANGE</div>
</div>
  </script>
</div>
```

Please pay attention to how I pass arguments to callback from directive it's very important to know that Angular using named arguments in this case.

Comment: I don't want to toggle it. Either way I'll need to create a model/variable in the controller. Right?

Comment: A toggle is just visualization/one of use-cases. Yes, but you also can pass value directly instead of a variable.

Comment: Thanks. Waiting for a few more answers :)

Comment: I tried your solution. Hides the button that I wanted to hide as expected. But as soon as I use ng-show or ng-if on the button that i want to hide, ng-click stops working (if any of those buttons are clicked a function is called) and I'm still trying to figure out why.

Comment: Could you please provide code that you're using? So will be easier to figure out your problem.

Comment: @AbhirathMahipal, I've added snippet with your case, hope it will help you!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really appreciate your time.